ASP.NET on .NET 4.8 on Azure throws error 403 after 20 minutes of inactivity
Access forbidden to my web app after 20 minutes of inactivity.
To avoid that, I need to refresh the page.
Once access forbidden has occurred, the only thing that works is to add or delete attribute debug="true" in the web.config file:
<system.web>
    <compilation *debug="true"* target framework="4.8" />
</system.web>

I have no access restrictions in my web app.
I cannot change in configuration settings. General settings. Always on. Because my service plan is not basic.
I have tried to allow access to 0.0.0.0/0 with priority 300 instead of enabled from all networks (networking - access restrictions) - but that's not working.
Session state timeout=6000 - is also not working.

Also, after some inactivity on the web app, I have an error : failed to load resource 404. I think it's due to the App_Start > RouteConfig.cs
`  public class RouteConfig
{
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Accounts", action = "Login", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );


    }
}`


As mentioned in the article, this issue can occur due to various reasons.

If you are using Free Pricing Tier, the error could be due to the site has reached the billing limit and site has been disabled.
The site has reached a resource quota limit which applies to Free or Shared Pricing Tiers.



It could also be due to the maximum number of connections. For Basic and below tiers, the maximum number of debug connections allowed is 1.

To resolve this error, scale up the Hosting plan depending on the quota that site has reached.

Quotas only apply to the Free and Shared Web Hosting Plan modes.


Enable Public Access under Web App=>Networking with no access restrictions.



Add the application setting WEBSITES_CONTAINER_START_TIME_LIMIT under the Environment variables to increase the time(in seconds) to wait for the container to complete start-up before restarting the container, can be increased up to the maximum of 1800 seconds.



I've checked your suggestions, unfortunately none is working . thanks anyway.

Restart the resource and check.

Solved : the only way to solve that, was to publish with option delete all existing files prior to publish.

Please post your fix as an answer to help the community.
